# Lag doesn't see the effects of mutate on previous rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I seem to have stumbled upon a `mutate/lag/ifelse` behaviour that I cannot explain. I have the following (simplified) dataframe:

```
test <- data.frame(type = c("START", "END", "START", "START", "START", "START", "END"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> test

  type
1 START
2   END
3 START
4 START
5 START
6 START
7 START
8   END
```

I would like to modify the column `type` in order to have a sequence of alternating `START` and `END` pairs (note that in the `test` dataframe only sequences of `START` are possible, `END` is never repeated):

```
> desired

  type
1 START
2   END
3 START
4   END
5 START
6   END
7 START
8   END
```

I thought I could achieve my goal with the following code:

```
test %>%
 mutate(type = ifelse( type == "START" &
                       dplyr::lag(type, n=1, default="END") == "START" &
                       dplyr::lead(type, n=1, default="END") == "START", "END" , type))
```

The code should detect rows in which `START` is preceded by a `START` and followed by a `START`, in which case the `type` value is changed to `END`. After this change, the following `START` (row number 5 of `test`) should not be matched, since its previous `type` value is now `END`. Unfortunately, the output of the command is the following:

```
   type
1 START
2   END
3 START
4   END
5   END
6   END
7 START
8   END
```

It's like the value seen by `lag` is not affected by mutate. Is this how it is supposed to work? Is there a way to code it in a way that `lag` sees the effects of `mutate` on the previous row?

Versions: R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10), dplyr_0.4.3

UPDATE: The reason why the above code doesn't work is explained by Paul Rougieux below: lead and lag are fixed and do not take into account further modification. So I guess the correct answer is "it cannot be done straightforwardly using dplyr".

Comment: Does this have to be solved using the scheme and the package you present or are you open to other solutions (using other functions)?

Comment: In general, I'd rather stick to dplyr, since I'm using it a lot and I would like to understand if this behaviour is "normal" or not. But if you have a solution that relies on other functions, that would still help a lot.

Comment: `test$type <- rep(unique(test$type),length.out = nrow(test))` ?

Comment: Note: it's very strange to *accept* an answer, then update your question as if it's not resolved. I think the issues you have are more with `ifelse` or R in general than specifically with `dplyr`. `ifelse` evaluates all of its arguments at once. All of the arguments you pass to `ifelse` are evaluated in the context at the point you pass them in. They are not repeatedly updated and re-evaluated during the execution of `ifelse`. With vectorized functions, don't think of operations as happening one-at-a-time, rather think of everything as happening all at once.

Comment: Generally, if you want to iterate on something where the results of one row are needed as inputs for the next row, (e.g., the Fibonacci sequence), it *can't* be vectorized and a for loop is appropriate.

Comment: To put it in the context of your comment on dataminer's answer: *"I didn't know that  lead/lag do not take into account modifications"* - the issue isn't specific to lead/lag, all vectorized functions behave this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining lag and lead variables separately in `mutate()` will show you that your call to `ifelse(type == "START" & lag   == "START" & lead == "START", "END" , type)`  is not going to work:

```
test <- data.frame(type = c("START", "END", "START", "START", "START", "START", "END"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test %>%
    mutate(lag = dplyr::lag(type, n=1, default="END"),
           lead = dplyr::lead(type, n=1, default="END"),
           type2 = ifelse(type == "START" & lag == "START" & lead == "START",
                          "END" , type))

#   type   lag  lead type2
#1 START   END   END START
#2   END START START   END
#3 START   END START START
#4 START START START   END
#5 START START START   END
#6 START START   END START
#7   END START   END   END
```

`dplyr::mutate()` modifies the vector as a whole. Lead and lag are fixed and do not take into account further modification to the `type` vector. What you want is a `Reduce()̀  function in this case. Check help(Reduce).

Comment: Yes, I know that. It's what I meant by "the value seen by lag is not affected by mutate". What I don't understand is why, and also if there is a way to make it behave like I was expecting it would.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 test$type[test$type != c("START", "END")] <- 
 ifelse(test$type[test$type != c("START", "END")] == "START", "END", "START")

test
   type
1 START
2   END
3 START
4   END
5 START
6   END
7 START
```

(The warnings can be ignored)

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. I gave more value to Paul Rougieux answer (even if it was partial, i.e., not providing an exact solution to the problem) because he framed it with respect to the dplyr package. I didn't know that lead/lag do not take into account modifications, and that's why my code didn't work. Thanks a lot for your answer, though.

Comment: To avoid warnings `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` you could create an object of the same length `goal <- rep(c("START", "END"), ceiling(nrow(test) / 2))[c(1:nrow(test))]` then use it in the comparison `test$type[test$type != goal] <- ifelse(test$type[test$type != goal] == "START", "END", "START")`. It looks like a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28logic%29), `goal` will always be equal to `test$type`.