# R: Create variable using iteratively updated values of previous row (=lag) similar to cumsum (depreciation)

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, data.table

My goal is to calculate take the add the `value`to a cumulative sum `csum` of the previous row multiplied by a scalar `delta`. Coming from Stata (where this is obvious), I didn't know that it would not work with `dplyr`'s `lag`function (see: [Lag doesn't see the effects of mutate on previous rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058326/lag-doesnt-see-the-effects-of-mutate-on-previous-rows)) and neither with `data.table`'s `shift` because both commands do not iteratively update the `csum`. It seems like some kind of a loop is required, but I can't figure out how to do it.

**Code that does *not* do the job**

```
delta= 0.94
df <- df %>% mutate(dcsum1 = value + delta*lag(csum, default=0))

setDT(df) #library(data.table) required
df$dcsumR2=df$csum
```

Example data & desired output:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tribble(~date, ~value,~csum,~dplyr_lag_output,~desired_output,
              "2017-01-01", 1,1,1,1,
              "2017-01-02", 2,3,2.94,2.94,
              "2017-01-03", NA,3,2.94,2.76,
              "2017-01-04", 3,6,5.82,5.49,
              "2017-01-05", 4,10,9.64,8.94 )
```

Comment: The tribble you provided doesn't seem to work : could you please test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Reduce` with `accumulate = T`:

```
Reduce(function(prev,value)  delta * prev + ifelse(is.na(value),0,value), x=df$value[-1], init = ifelse(is.na(df$value[1]),0,df$value[1]), accumulate = T)

[1] 1.000000 2.940000 2.763600 5.597784 9.261917
```

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[,output:=Reduce(function(prev,value)  delta * prev + ifelse(is.na(value),0,value), x=value[-1], init = ifelse(is.na(value[1]),0,value[1]), accumulate = T)]
```

Comment: In the tribble you provided `desired_outpout` doesn't change after NA : to my understanding, the factor doesn't seem to be applied

Comment: see my edit, you can decide whether you use `delta*prev` or `prev` in the `ifelse`

Comment: I extended the tribble by a group variable (3 groups with 5 rows each) and added `by=group`, using `data.table` (same problem occurs with `dplyr::group_by`.  I get the error: `Supplied 15 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 5 in column 'output'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code. ` How can I avoid that?

Comment: this was a copy-paste error: I left `df$value` in the `data.table` version, it should of course be `value` only . See my edit.